# Export Issue with Datatable to CSV

Tags: c#, json, csv, ext.net

I have used ext.net 1.6 tool. I tried to convert data datatable to csv but i am getting error status code : 200 and status text : Bad Request.

And I also exported data from ext.net gridpanel to csv but now i want to export directly datatable to csv.

I passed Jason string for datatable same as passed for gridpanel but gridpanel data is exported perfectly, but datatable does not export with same method

can you suggest me?

what is exact problem with that?

Thanks

Comment: thanks @Artemix ..do u have any solutions?

Comment: No, but I hope that adding relevant tags will help to bring here the ones who might know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below

Method to convert the Datatable data to export into CSV in c#:

```
void ToCSVDownload(DataTable dtDataTable)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

    //Writing Headers
    for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(dtDataTable.Columns[i]);
        if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

    //Writing Data
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataTable.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
            {
                string value = dr[i].ToString();
                if (value.Contains(','))
                {
                    value = String.Format("\"{0}\"", value);
                    sw.Write(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                }
            }
            if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }
    sw.Close();

    //converting it to the Bytes 
    byte[] byteArray = stream.ToArray();


    //Dowloading the file by writing Bytes
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename = test.csv");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain your code a bit more so others can understand not only *if* this solves their problem, but also *why* this solves their problem. Answers containing large blocks of code and little to no explanation aren't very useful in the sense that it's hard to tell if it actually answers the question.